# How to use a glossary exposed filter in search api views?

Tags: 8, views, search

I have a search api views. I want to display a glossary filter on title.

[image]

I have searched many articles to implement it using a contextual filters. But the options of context filters can be seen in a normal view but not in search api views. i-e When the filter value is not available, display a summary

I also tried this  module [Search API AZ Glossary](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_glossary) but I do not want it as a facet.

So my questions is, Is this possible with a normal views exposed filter or with a contextual filter etc?

I don't see the summary options here as this is present in a normal view.
[image]

Nor these settings are present in search api views.
[image]

Comment: Views come with the Glossary Views, you just have to enable them. Or edit it to find out how to build it on your own in a different Views. You need the Contextual filter for the Title, on Page it takes fixed value to start with nodes beginning with "a", the Attachment is set to Summary. Nothing is inherited in Attachment settings.

Comment: @prkos Yes, I know but the options in the contextual filter of a search api views is different from the normal view as I stated in the question. We can't set the attachment to Summary.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots. Please see

Comment: I don't see those options either, in normal Views. Glossary Views does it a bit differently than More options, check it out.

Comment: What did you wind up doing @Ahmad